# Display date and time in header

Tags: 8, datetime

I would like to display current date and time to the header section.

I am using a subtheme of Bartik. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You can also add code `page.html.twig` as well.

For print only date use `{{ "now"|date("m/d/Y") }}`

More Details

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/date.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364206/symfony2-how-can-i-set-twig-dated-f-y-filter-to-output-months-in-swedish

Comment: Does this take into account site/user TZ settings, localization, and handle cache contexts properly?

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment directly on Smalution's answer, but can confirm that

`{{ "now"|date("m/d/Y") }}`

in twig DOES respect drupal user timezones. (Tested it in america/new york - 2:50, switched to america/edmonton - 12:50) as per  mpdonadio's question.

Comment: This should not be an answer, it should be a comment on the DRUPWAY´s answer.

Answer (score -1):

For this you can create custom block and insert the PHP date function in it. (Install PHP module for insert php code in block or drupal site).
Place this block on the header or where you want to place.

[image]

Comment: Does this take into account site/user TZ settings, localization, and handle cache contexts properly?

Comment: Also not advised to inject PHP code as body content.